# jackson XML serialization: list of inherited classes

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I want to serialize/deserialize such XML:

```
<Multi>
    <child-001>
        <name/>
        <value/>
    </child-001>
    <child-002>
        <name/>
        <value/>
    </child-002>
</Multi>
```

where the child-001 and child-002 are classes inherited from the same parent.

```
public abstract class Parent {
    private String name;
}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "child-001")
public class Child001 extends Parent {
    private String value;
}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "child-002")
public class Child002 extends Parent {
    private String value;
}
```

The encapsulating class looks like this:

```
class Multi {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Parent> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Without @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false) I've got:

```
<Multi>
  <nodes>
    <nodes>
      <name>name001</name>
      <value>value001</value>
    </nodes>
    <nodes>
      <name>name002</name>
      <value>value002</value>
    </nodes>
  </nodes>
</Multi>
```

With the annotation I've got:

```
<Multi>
  <nodes>
    <name>name001</name>
    <value>value001</value>
  </nodes>
  <nodes>
    <name>name002</name>
    <value>value002</value>
  </nodes>
</Multi>
```

This is quite close to what I need, but still need to replace "nodes" with "child-001" and "child-002".

Can someone point me where to find a solution? Or should I use JAXB instead of Jackson?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Normally to represent exaclty the example XML file, `Multi` class should look like this and this works well:

```
class Multi {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "child-001")
    private Child001 child001;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "child-002")
    private Child002 child002;
}
```

In your code you are using a `List` of objects of parent class instead, presumably because you may have any number of elements deserialized into subclasses of `Parent` ? That's a case of polymorphic deserialization that requires defining type info e.g.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "child-001", value = Child001.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "child-002", value = Child002.class)
})
abstract class Parent {
    private String name;
}
```

Unfortunately, due to an as yet (jackson 2.9.2) unresolved [issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/issues/51) Jackson expects a wrapper around each element e.g.

```
<Multi>
  <nodes>
    <child-001>
      <name>n1</name>
      <value>v1</value>
    </child-001>
  </nodes>
  <nodes>
    <child-002>
      <name>n2</name>
      <value>v2</value>
    </child-002>
  </nodes>
</Multi>
```

Until this issue is resolved consider if the first option. If there are fields you don't want serialized leave them null.

Comment: Yes, there can any number of elements, thus the list. Thanks for the answer. I have defined structure so I have to find another way, but thanks again.