# Jackson XML - change tag according to the property type

Tags: java, jackson, xmlmapper

How can I change a root tag from a property according to the class type of a property?

Consider this code:

```
public class Animal {
  private String name;
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
}

public class Person {
  private String name;
  private Animal pet;
}

Person p1 = new Person("P1");
p1.setPet(new Dog("Pluto"));
System.out.println(new XMlMapper().writeValueAsString(p1));

Person p2 = new Person("P2");
p2.setPet(new Cat("Tom"));
System.out.println(new XMlMapper().writeValueAsString(p2));
```

I want this output:

```
<person>
  <name>P1</name>
  <dog>
    <name>Pluto</name>
  </dog>
</person>

<person>
  <name>P2</name>
  <cat>
    <name>Tom</name>
  </cat>
</person>
```

How can I do it using Jackson?

Comment: I came up with an improvised solution by creating a serializer for the Person class, but it didn't turn out elegant. I have other classes in similar situations within the project, and this generates extra work that I would like to avoid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jackson XML serialization: list of inherited classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48155494/jackson-xml-serialization-list-of-inherited-classes)

Comment: The solution you indicated proposes to wrap the class in a list just to force this effect. Are you sure it's a good solution?

Comment: You missed the point. The list is the detail of that implementation. The real thing for you are the annotations at either property level or class level that will identify your classes to the xml nodes.

Comment: With @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT) an extra tag is added in the xml: "<person><name>P1</name><pet><dog><name>Pluto </name></dog></pet></person>". That's why in the other thread they added a list, to try to use the @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false) feature to remove the outermost tag. As we say in Portuguese, a tremendous "gambiarra".

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a "gambiarra" as it is defined at the Jackson specification it needs a wrapper. They mentioned it on their answer. You might be able to do it with a Custom Deserializer though. Not sure if the custom one you created is doing it properly if so, you already have the most elegant way of solving it :)